# Notation for referring to specific graph colourings

Tags: notation, coloring, polygons, tiling, permutation-cycles

Consider the following four graphs where $k$ represents the number of colours used to colour the vertices of each graph.

Here cycle graphs are used to represent regular polygons, in this specific case the hexagon. The tiling of interest is thus

[image]

where we are wondering about the color of each triangular tile and represent each tile with a vertex in the cycle graphs below.

[image]

I am looking for a notation similar to e.g. the Schläfli symbol (though others will do too), allowing me to refer to a specific colouring. For example, I cannot find a notation that lets me refer to the pattern in Figure (b). The Schläfli symbol for the tiling of the hexagon would be $\{3,6\}$ but is there an extension for colouring? It would seem that I require another dimension to the current notation to describe a specific colouring.

Very new to this field, any pointers would be very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Are $b$, $c$ and $d$ referring to the coloring of an hexagonal tiling, or are they just a coloring of an hexagon ? I don't see how $c$ can transfer in an hexagonal tiling... What kind of graphs are you dealing with? polyhedral symmetric graphs or arbitrary graphs?

Comment: Hi, good questions let me add some more detail. a,b,c and d are four different ways of coloring the hexagon which here is represented by the cycle graphs which can be drawn as regular polygons. The circle graphs just represent a regular tiling of the hexagon using the triangle as the prototile, where the colour of each triangle is represented by the vertex colour shown above.